# How do I add a TypeScript definitely typed definition in ASP.NET 5?

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015, definitelytyped, tsd

I'm trying to install TypeScript definition files from DefinitelyTyped within a ASP.NET v5 web project in Visual Studio 2015 RC? NuGet packages don't seem to work anymore and TSD hasn't been updated in awhile and I haven't seen a lot of good documentation for it when using it within VS.

What ways are still working for the VS 2015 RC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TSD is [deprecated](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd/issues/269). The generally preferred alternative is [Typings](https://github.com/typings/typings).

From docs:

> # Install Typings CLI utility.
>   **npm install typings --global**
>
> # Search for definitions.
>   **typings search tape**
>
> # Find an available definition (by name).
>   **typings search --name react**
>
> # If you use the package as a module:
>   # Install non-ambient typings (default from "npm" registry, configurable through `defaultSource` in `.typingsrc`)
>   **typings install debug --save**
>
> # If you use the package through script tag, or
>   # it is part of the environment, or
>   # the non-ambient typings is not yet available:
>   **typings install dt~mocha --global --save**
>
> # Install typings from particular registry
>   **typings install env~atom --global --save**
>   **typings install npm~bluebird --save**
>
> # Use `typings/index.d.ts` (in `tsconfig.json` or as a `///` reference).
>   **cat typings/index.d.ts**

Comment: Since tsc 2 typings are deprecated too if i'm right, just pull in the "@type/modulname" package with npm

Comment: @MrKekson Is it? Who says so?

Comment: Here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/

Answer (score 6):

I have been using TSD from NPM. It is working fine with my MVC 6 project and should definitely be the most up to date source of definitions.

This should be all you need to get going:

```
npm install tsd --save-dev
tsd install jquery --save
```

Comment: Thanks. It look me awhile to figure out how to get npm properly installed as you can't just use it. Also git has to be locally installed as well with command-line mode. I was hoping of finding a way to do it code-first instead of command-line first, but the commit codes for tsd.json don't seem that easy to use compared to using tsd install.