# How to get Typescript typings in VS 2015 with ASP.NET 5

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I've tried adding the DefinitelyTyped NuGet packages, but they don't seem to add any content to my project so I don't know how to reference them.

It looks like I should use TSD, but does that apply to every project? How does TSD know what typings I want for each project? I found this that mentions TSD: [How do I add a TypeScript definitely typed definition in ASP.NET 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994427/how-do-i-add-a-typescript-definitely-typed-definition-in-asp-net-5)

Is there a new way that it's supposed to be done? I found the "Search for typings" in the context menu when you right click on a .js file, but that just does a NuGet search.

Comment: Did you find a solution?